# Controlling cell width in RStudio Environment tab data viewer

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using the latest version of `RStudio` on Mac (1.2.1070). When viewing a data frame in the Environment tab, the cell widths are very wide, seemingly as wide as the data contained. This makes it hard to use with large text blocks. Is there a way to control the default width of cells or to set a max default width, other than by manually dragging using the mouse?

I think this behaviour is recent, and only in the latest release of `RStudio`.

Answer (score 3):

In `RStudio\resources\grid` folder, locate `dtstyles.css` file, look for `.textCell` there should be several. Find the one contains `max-width: 300px;` and change the number. See if it works.

Comment: Thanks. Did not make a difference. Actually cells seem to be as wide as the text needs to be so way off screen. The line in `dtstyles.css` is  `.autoSize .numberCell, .autoSize .textCell, 
.autoSize .dataCell, .autoSize .listCell {
    max-width: 300px; 
}`  Can I remove `.autoSize`? I need to have max width when first viewed, but allow expansion manally.

Comment: **Update**. I reinstalled and all seems fine. :-)